# Melhor estrutura de BD com grande número de dados e colunas filtráveis

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados, índices

Possuo um banco de dados Mysql com uma tabela que está demorando muito para completar uma query.
Gostaria de saber qual seria a melhor estrutura de banco de dados indicado para uma tabela com muitos campos que são passíveis de filtros, possuem mais de 5 milhões de registros e que é alimentada constantemente.

Todos os campos filtráveis estão indexados.

A VM em que está o banco de dados possui os atributos:

```
Sistema Operacional CentOS 6.X 64 bits
Mysql 5.7
CPU 2 x 2 Cores
6 GB Memória
```

Atualmente a estrutura que existe é a seguinte:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `vendas` (
  `identificador` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `doc` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `emissao` date NOT NULL,
  `recno` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `filial` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `filial_origem` varchar(5) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `cliente` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dap` bigint(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `referencia` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `grupo` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `prefixo` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `descricao` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `data_hora` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `quantidade` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `valor_unitario` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `total` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `desconto` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `custo_unitario` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `custo_medio` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `pedido` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `posicao` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `tabela` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `atividade` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `risco` varchar(5) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `uf` varchar(3) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `municipio` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `regiao` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `fornecedor` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vendedor` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vendedor2` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `aplicador` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tipo` varchar(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `motivo` varchar(5) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `pm` double(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`identificador`,`emissao`),
  KEY `filial` (`filial`),
  KEY `dap` (`dap`),
  KEY `referencia` (`referencia`),
  KEY `grupo` (`grupo`),
  KEY `tabela` (`tabela`),
  KEY `atividade` (`atividade`),
  KEY `municipio` (`municipio`),
  KEY `fornecedor` (`fornecedor`),
  KEY `vendedor` (`vendedor`),
  KEY `aplicador` (`aplicador`),
  KEY `flaged` (`flaged`),
  KEY `tipo` (`tipo`),
  KEY `cliente` (`cliente`),
  KEY `emissao` (`emissao`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Este exemplo de consulta está demorando cerca de 11 segundos, o que é insatisfatório:

```
select CONCAT_WS("-",YEAR(emissao),LPAD(MONTH(emissao),2,'0')),
sum(total) as faturamento
from `vendas` as `operacao` 
where (`emissao` >= '2009-01-01')
group by 1
order by 1
```

O que eu poderia melhorar nessa estrutura para que consultas como a do exemplo tragam resultados com menos de 1 segundo?

------------------ UPDATE

Resultado da query abaixo (com particionamento 'emissao' por periodo anual):

```
explain select CONCAT_WS("-",YEAR(emissao),LPAD(MONTH(emissao),2,'0')),
sum(total) as faturamento
from `vendas` as `operacao` 
where (`emissao` >= '2009-01-01')
group by 1
order by 1
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O resultado da query `show index from vendas`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Chegou a olhar o plano de execução da consulta? sabe dizer se os itens mais procurados são sempre os mais recentes? se sim pode deixar eles em cache. Já pensou em particionar a tabela?

Comment: Estatisticas atualizadas ? Utilização de índices ? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-statistics.html     https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization-indexes.html   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html

Comment: @rray atualizei agora com mais alguns detalhes usando o explain e o show index. 
Sim, já tentei usar o particionamento, mas não deu nenhuma melhora significativa.

Comment: Recomendo a leitura: [Como melhorar a performance de leitura de um banco de dados SQL?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/173358/como-melhorar-a-performance-de-leitura-de-um-banco-de-dados-sql)

Answer (score 2):

Pelo que pude analisar da saída do comando `EXPLAIN`, sua query não está utilizando nenhum indice, pois você está forçando a utilização de funções tanto para ordenação quanto para o agrupamento.

Uma alternativa para a sua query seria:

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT_WS("-",YEAR(emissao), LPAD(MONTH(emissao),2,'0')),
  SUM(total) AS faturamento
FROM `vendas` AS `operacao` 
WHERE (`emissao` >= '2009-01-01')
GROUP BY emissao
```

Esta consulta irá agrupar os registros por dia, gerando um resultado um pouco diferente do que você possui. Caso deseje agrupar por mês e ano como sua query já fazia, utilize esta consulta:

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT_WS("-",YEAR(emissao), LPAD(MONTH(emissao),2,'0')),
  SUM(total) AS faturamento
FROM `vendas` AS `operacao` 
WHERE (`emissao` >= '2009-01-01')
GROUP BY YEAR(emissao), MONTH(emissao)
```

**Nota 1**: Ao invés de utilizar o número 1, indicando o primeiro campo da consulta, estou utilizando o nome do campo, garantindo a utilização do índice.

**Nota 2**: Como você está utilizando o comando `GROUP BY` na coluna `emissao`, não há necessidade de utilizar o comando `ORDER BY` pois o agrupamento já garante a ordem dos registros.