# Como funciona a seletividade de índices

Tags: sql, sql-server, índices

Lendo sobre índices me deparei recentemente com o termo "seletividade". Alguns lugares diziam que os campos mais seletivos devem vir primeiro no índice, outros dizem que não ou que depende.

Tenho a seguinte tabela `tbMovimentoConta` abreviação (`mcon`) com 5 milhões de registros, e as seguintes colunas que serão usadas no `where`

- mcon_dataExclusao (99% do registros tem o valor `null`) porque os dados não podem ser excluídos com `delete from`
- con_codigo_fk (há 5 valores distintos(1,2,3,4,5) divididos para os 5 milhões de registros)
- mcon_data (1825 datas distintas para os 5 milhões de registros)

Tenho a seguinte consulta que é gerada pelo Entity Framework:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Project1].[C2] AS [C1], 
[Project1].[mcon_codigo_pk] AS [mcon_codigo_pk], 
[Project1].[mcon_data] AS [mcon_data], 
[Project1].[mcon_obs] AS [mcon_obs], 
[Project1].[mcon_valor] AS [mcon_valor], 
[Project1].[mcon_tipo] AS [mcon_tipo]
FROM ( SELECT 
    convert (datetime2, convert(varchar(255), [Extent1].[mcon_data], 102) ,  102) AS [C1], 
    [Extent1].[mcon_codigo_pk] AS [mcon_codigo_pk], 
    [Extent1].[mcon_data] AS [mcon_data], 
    [Extent1].[mcon_valor] AS [mcon_valor], 
    [Extent1].[mcon_tipo] AS [mcon_tipo], 
    [Extent1].[mcon_obs] AS [mcon_obs], 
    1 AS [C2]
    FROM [dbo].[tbMovimentoConta] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[mcon_data] >= @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[mcon_data] <= @p__linq__1) AND ([Extent1].[con_codigo_fk] = @p__linq__2) AND ([Extent1].[mcon_dataExclusao] IS NULL)
)  AS [Project1]
ORDER BY [Project1].[C1] ASC, [Project1].[mcon_codigo_pk] ASC
OFFSET 764225 ROWS FETCH NEXT 11 ROWS ONLY ',N'@p__linq__0 datetime2(7),@p__linq__1 datetime2(7),@p__linq__2 bigint',@p__linq__0='2012-01-01 00:00:00',@p__linq__1='2013-01-01 23:59:59',@p__linq__2=1
```

Eu testei com duas configurações de índice

Índice 1

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ix_consulta_movimento] ON [dbo].[tbMovimentoConta]
(
    [mcon_dataExclusao] ASC,
    [con_codigo_fk] ASC,
    [mcon_data] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   
[mcon_dataInclusao],
[mcon_codigo_pk],
[mcon_valor],
[mcon_tipo],
[mcon_obs]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
GO
```

Índice 2

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ix_consulta_movimento] ON [dbo].[tbMovimentoConta]
(
    [mcon_data] ASC,
    [con_codigo_fk] ASC,
    [mcon_dataExclusao] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   
[mcon_dataInclusao],
[mcon_codigo_pk],
[mcon_valor],
[mcon_tipo],
[mcon_obs]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
GO
```

Nos testes que fiz, o índice 1 foi mais rápido, porém achei que o 2 seria mais rápido. Alguém poderia me explicar porque o índice 1 é mais rápido, ou se tem coisa errado nisso, sendo assim o 2 teria que ser mais rápido.

**Edição**

Fazendo mais testes aqui, parece que o índice 2 é mais rápido mesmo. De qualquer forma estou dúvida. Preciso ter o claro entendimento de como ordenar essas colunas no índice.

Comment: Depende do que precisa. Se você colocar o `ID` em primeiro você terá uma ótima seletividade, mas se deseja um grupo de informações entre datas, isso não ajuda em nada. Se fizer cegamente acabará criando dezenas de índices, a maioria sem necessidade real e poderá ter perda de performance em outros pontos.

Comment: Vou editar a pergunta. Peguei no trace a query que o Entity Framework está gerando, e vou completar os includes columns do índice que faltou.

Comment: Talvez uma analise do plano de execução da consulta pode ajudar a entender. O plano inclui as estratégias de JOIN e de WHERE que podem trazer melhores respostas do que apenas a questão de escolha dos índices.

Comment: Eu fiz isso, na verdade ele que sugeriu o índice 1, eu criei o índice dois.

Comment: Quem tiver interesse em entender mais sobre índices tem 3 livros que são FREE e bons. http://www.red-gate.com/library/sql-server-execution-plans-2nd-edition , http://www.red-gate.com/community/books/inside-sql-server-query-optimizer e https://www.simple-talk.com/books/sql-books/complete-showplan-operators/

Comment: coloquei nessa resposta um comando para verificar indice faltando, veja se ajuda, e também sempre analise o plano de consulta, lembrando que todo indice criado causa impacto no insert, update e delete.

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/173358/como-melhorar-a-performance-de-leitura-de-um-banco-de-dados-sql/173899#173899

Comment: Depois mostra o plano de execução, só com ele pode ter certeza se a query rodou mais ou menos rapido.

Answer (score 1):

*"o índice 1 foi mais rápido, porém achei que o 2 seria mais rápido"*

Para responder essa pergunta, precisamos lembrar que um índice é uma lista ordenada por um ou mais campos com um ponteiro que aponta para o registro correspondente na tabela.

Como ele está ordenado, a busca é muito mais rápida, evitando o *"table scan"* que acontece quando pesquisamos por um campo não ordenado, ou seja uma pesquisa completa na tabela.

A resposta para a sua pergunta é bem simples, ainda mais com um detalhe importante: *"99% do registros tem o valor null"*, ou seja, os registros null vão vir todos em sequência no índice, o que significa que, ao procurar por um valor, vai limitar a busca a apenas 1% do índice, fazendo com que seja muito rápido.

Para tentar ilustrar, imagine que o índice fosse algo assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja, qualquer data vai estar naquela "pequena" parte do índice, toda a parte "null" vai ser pulada, resultando numa busca muito mais rápida, isso porque o campo `mcon_dataExclusao` é logo o primeiro do índice, limitando muito a pesquisa.

Answer (score 0):

Os índices servem para facilitar na hora de selecionar os dados que serão retornados pelas consulta. Para índices compostos, ou seja, aqueles que apresentam mais de uma coluna em sua estrutura, a ordem das mesmas servem para melhorar o processo de SCAN nas tabelas que o SGBD faz na hora que se realiza uma operação sobre a mesma. Existem alguns critérios e diretrizes para a ordenação das mesmas seguindo o conceito de seletividade:

- Colunas que aparecem na cláusula WHERE devem ocupar uma posição superior inicial;
- Colunas que aparecem mais frequentemente na cláusula WHERE, ordene essas colunas no índice para que as selecionadas mais frequentemente aparecem em uma posição superior;
- Se as colunas aparecem na mesma frequência, mas os dados estiverem fisicamente ordenados em uma das colunas, coloque-a em uma posição superior;
- Caso a coluna seja muito esparsa, ou seja, apresente muitos valores NULL com relação as outras, ela deve ser ordenada em uma posição inferior com relação às outras.