# Consulta Lenta - SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, query

A query abaixo está demorando em média 30 segundos para executar. Sei que bem muito provável pode ser os vários *or* e *like*, mas estou buscando da tabela de log e nem sempre os *id* serão iguais, por isso que utilizei o *like*. Como ajustar essa consulta para se tornar mais rapida?

```
select max(l.logdescricao),  
S.SolID [N° Chamado],  
S.NomeCliente [Nome Cliente],  
MAX(T.TraData) [Data do Último Trâmite],  
U.UsuNome [Consultor Responsável]  
from Solicitacao S  
inner join Log L on S.SolID = L.LogSolID  
LEFT JOIN Usuario U  
ON U.UsuID = S.UsuIDResponsavel  
LEFT JOIN Tramite T  
ON T.SolID = S.SolID  
left join StatusMotivo SM ON SM.SMSolID = S.SolID  
where S.VencimentoPausado = 0 and S.SolStatus <> 9 and (L.LOGDESCRICAO like '%16357%Aguardando%Operadora%' or L.LOGDESCRICAO like '%1061%Aguardando%Cliente%'
or L.LOGDESCRICAO like '%1061%Aguardando%Desenvolvimento%' or L.LOGDESCRICAO like '%1061%Aguardando%Operadora%')  
group by S.SolID,S.NomeCliente,U.UsuNome
```

Comment: Com diversos `LIKE` com `%` acho que não tem muito como melhorar

Comment: Pode dar uma olhada nas respostas dessa pergunta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/173358/como-melhorar-a-performance-de-leitura-de-um-banco-de-dados-sql

Comment: @RenanBessa: Poderia acrescentar, na descrição da pergunta, informações como : (1) Qual é o objetivo da consulta?  (2) O que contém e como está estruturada a coluna LOGDESCRICAO? // Achei estranho o uso de % no meio das sequências.  // As sequências devem ser procuradas ao longo do conteúdo de LOGDESCRICAO ou a partir do início?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Renan, você utiliza 2 campos que são do tipo inteiro (S.VencimentoPausado e S.SolStatus) para fazer o filtro além do campo de texto. Se colocar um índice que contenha esses campos, a consulta certamente será mais rápida. Pode utilizar também o plano de execução para ver se o SQL Server sugere a criação de algum índice. Veja no link a seguir como isso funciona: [Missing index](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-missing-index-details-transact-sql)