# Qual a melhor prática para se fazer uma consulta em tabelas grandes?

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, operador-like, full-text

Tenho um sistema composto por várias tabelas.Uma das tabelas chama-se `Publications` e contém 15 campos variados, sendo 3 deles os principais da minha dúvida:

```
 1. titulo - varchar(100)
 2. subtitulo - varchar(200)
 3. texto - text
```

Em pouco tempo (18 meses +/-) essa tabela terá mais de 1 milhão de registros e estamos preocupados com a performance das procuras por registros.

Qual a melhor forma de fazer consultas por palavras chaves inseridas pelos usuários em um formulário, utilizando-se o *LIKE* ou *FULLTEXT* ou tanto faz?

Estamos preocupados com buscas por palavras compostas como por exemplo "*house music*" e principalmente velocidade e desempenho nos processos.

Por onde eu começo, estou acostumado com *queries* mais simples e menos impactantes e não estou sabendo lidar com todas as variáveis envolvidas.

Comment: Eu costumo seguir isto quando a coisa aperta: [10 técnicas para otimização de instruções SQL](https://imasters.com.br/artigo/22264/banco-de-dados/10-tecnicas-para-otimizacao-de-instrucoes-sql?trace=1519021197&source=single)

Comment: @Marconi o tipo de banco de dados e a linguagem são importantes na pergunta, você não concorda?

Comment: Por se tratar de um série histórica, costuma-se fazer partições por data, mantendo apenas os registros mais recentes na tabela principal e os mais antigos nas tabelas ou partições secundárias. No Sql-Server sei que existem ferramentas que automatizam a criação e as cargas de registros destas partições. Se no MySql não existir essas funções, pode fazer isso de forma manual. Ou seja, migrar os registros antigos e separar as consultas, fazendo a segunda consulta somente se necessário.

Comment: Relacionado: [Como melhorar a performance de leitura de um banco de dados SQL?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/173358/como-melhorar-a-performance-de-leitura-de-um-banco-de-dados-sql)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"A melhor prática" é criar um ambiente de desenvolvimento que simule a situação que encontrará e criar soluções para ver o que é mais adequado.

A solução mais simples é um `LIKE`, tente com ele e veja se os resultados são satisfatórios. Se não forem passe para um sistema de busca de texto dedicado e configurado adequadamente.

Me parece que a performance não deve ser problema em máquinas razoáveis. Precisaria ver se terá muito acesso concorrente ou pouco, se será só local. Desenvolver a aplicação de forma correta também conta. A arquitetura correta pode pesar mais do que escolher este ou aquele recurso do banco de dados.

Dependendo do tipo de resposta que deseje precisaria de um mecanismo de busca textual especializado.

Comment: Fizemos um ambiente de teste com 2,5 milhões de registros e as consultas estão demorando cerca de 3,5 segundos (muito). Além dos resultados estarem sendo ineficientes. Precisaríamos de full-text mesmo, pelo menos pensamos. Mas não dominamos isso a fundo...

Comment: Precisa ver se não tem como otimizar isso antes. De qualquer forma vale o teste com FTS.

Comment: Pesquisamos algumas coisas por aqui. Mudaremos o foco para pesquisa fulltext. Além de termos um desempenho melhor conseguimos resultados mais poderosos para o usuário.