# Como simular carga em um banco de dados?

Tags: sql-server, testes, teste-stress

Tenho um banco de dados SQL Server que recentemente teve problemas de performance em produção pela grande quantidade de usuários simultâneos somado à alguns problemas de implementação e arquitetura.

Após tomar [algumas medidas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/173358/como-melhorar-a-performance-de-leitura-de-um-banco-de-dados-sql) para minimizar os problemas, preciso testar essas mudanças sem que seja no servidor de produção.

Como simular tal carga, de uma quantidade de usuários (em média 4000 máquinas) e muitas *queries* para saber se tais alterações surtiram efeito?

Não sei se esta pergunta cai no caso [daquela que já propõe uma solução](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/499/o-que-%C3%A9-o-problema-xy) (problema XY). Sendo assim, que outra forma eu teria de testar minhas mudanças?

Answer (score 4):

Estes tipo de testes que você deseja realizar chamam teste de estresse.

**Teste de Estresse**

**Ferramentas**

No caso do sql server, existe uma ferramente chamada [sqlquerystress](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2016/01/04/sqlquerystress-the-source-code.aspx), que pode te ajudar a fazer estes teste. Com ela é possível:

- Verificar o comportamento da instância com uma determinada quantidade de sessões em execução
- Executar várias queries ao mesmo tempo para estressar a CPU, disco e memória do servidor e verificar o seu comportamento
- Simulação de um ambiente crítico com várias transações por segundo durante os testes de sistemas e consultas SQL
- Identificar quantas vezes uma SP é executada por dia, realizar uma otimização e simular qual seria o ganho de tempo no dia
- Executar uma query ou SP várias vezes, com parâmetros aleatórios e analisar seu comportamento

**Como Utilizar**

Após baixar o executável da ferramenta, você verá a tela inicial do SQLQueryStress. Clique no botão “Database” para configurar a conexão com o banco de dados.

Não recomendo a utilização desse software em ambientes de produção, a não ser que seja em um horário de manutenção agendada e que você queira fazer testes de stress na instância.

Tela inicial do SQLQueryStress
Nesta tela, você poderá digitar o nome do servidor\instância de conexão, bem como dados de tipo de autenticação, usuário e senha.

Tela de configuração de conexão com o banco de dados
De volta à tela inicial, vamos definir a query que será executada, os parâmetros de execução e iniciar o processamento.

Parâmetros de execução:
– Number of Iterations: É o número de vezes que a query será executada
– Number of Threads: Número de sessões que serão executadas em paralelo (ao mesmo tempo)
– Delay between queries (ms): Quantidade de millisegundos entre o fim de uma query e o início da próxima.

Vale ressaltar que o número de vezes que a query será executada é através da conta Number of Iterations x Number of Threads, ou seja, se você colocar 10 iterações com 5 threads, a sua query será executada 50 vezes.

Fonte:https://www.dirceuresende.com/blog/sql-server-utilizando-a-ferramenta-sqlquerystress-para-otimizar-suas-consultas-sql/